# Google image pie chart labels not working

Tags: google-visualization

I am using the old static Google Chart API to generate a pie chart. The URL I am using is

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p&chs=150x150&chd=t:1,2,3&chl=a|b|c
```

This URL contains the required parameter – chl – for labels, specified in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts#pie_chart_label)

However, the image comes back with only lines pointing to the slices, not labels. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: the width in the `chs` parameter was too small for the labels to show up.